# Android Studio Bluetooth ListView

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I wanted to make bluetooth applications for arduino so that I could connect to the HC-05 module. And I found a tutorial on how to make a bluetooth connection (http://mcuhq.com/27/simple-android-bluetooth-application-with-arduino-example) When I downloaded the code from github, the application starts and everything works and connects. But the problem is that I can't open a new activity because the project is probably for 15 API and the new activity needs at least 16 so I decided to make such an application on my own based on the code from this website. And here I have a problem because when I make my phone search for bluetooth devices, nothing is displayed on my ListView.
This is my code `

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        offon = findViewById(R.id.BtBtn);
        TV = findViewById(R.id.BtTv);
        TV2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TV3 = findViewById(R.id.bluetooth_status);
        Next = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        LV = findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        disc = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        LV.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter);
        LV.setOnItemClickListener(DeviceList);

        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                if(msg.what == MESSAGE_READ){
                    String readMessage = null;
                    readMessage = new String((byte[]) msg.obj, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    TV2.setText(readMessage);
                }

                if(msg.what == CONNECTING_STATUS){
                    char[] sConnected;
                    if(msg.arg1 == 1)
                        TV3.setText(getString(R.string.BTConnected) + msg.obj);
                    else
                        TV3.setText(getString(R.string.BTconnFail));
                }
            }
        };

        if (adapter.isEnabled()){
            TV.setText("Bluetooth ON");
        }else TV.setText("Bluetooth OFF");
       disc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                discovery();
                if (!adapter.isEnabled()){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.BTnotOn), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        offon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (adapter.isEnabled()) {
                    adapter.disable();
                   TV.setText("Bluetooth OFF");
                }else {
                    adapter.enable();
                    TV.setText("Bluetooth ON");
                }
            }
        });
        Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                open2activity();
            }
        });

    }
    public void open2activity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent Data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, Data);

    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void discovery(){
        if (adapter.isDiscovering()){
            adapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.DisStop), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            if (adapter.isEnabled()){
                ArrayAdapter.clear();
                adapter.startDiscovery();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.DisStart), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                registerReceiver(blReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
            }
        }
    }

    final BroadcastReceiver blReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                ArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener DeviceList = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TV3.setText(getString(R.string.cConnet));
            String info = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
            final String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
            final String name = info.substring(0,info.length() - 17);
            new Thread()
            {
                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    boolean fail = false;

                    BluetoothDevice device = adapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

                    try {
                        BTSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        fail = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.ErrSockCrea), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    try {
                        BTSocket.connect();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        try {
                            fail = true;
                            BTSocket.close();
                            handler.obtainMessage(CONNECTING_STATUS, -1, -1)
                                    .sendToTarget();
                        } catch (IOException e2) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(ErrSockCrea), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    if(!fail) {
                        ConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(BTSocket, handler);
                        ConnectedThread.start();

                        handler.obtainMessage(CONNECTING_STATUS, 1, -1, name)
                                .sendToTarget();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
        try {
            final Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", UUID.class);
            return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, BT_MODULE_UUID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
        }
        return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BT_MODULE_UUID);
    }

}
```

`

I tried to do as above but nothing is displayed